# how to make a same operation for multiple textbox values that having same id in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a page that contain multiple text boxes generated by according to how many persons in db. for each person one text box will appeared and the given value will stored when leaving that text box. Inthis case i get value for 1st text box after that the value didnt get can anyone give any jquery or razor function. here the text box id's are same whether i need to change the id ? give some code examples

```
thanks 


My razor syntax is look like



 @{List<string> subGroups = new List<string>();}
   @foreach (var account in Model.AnnualBudget.Accounts)
                        {

                            if (account.AccountName == "Others")
                            { continue; }
                            if (!subGroups.Exists(sg => sg.Contains(account.AccountHead.AccountHeadName)))
                            {
                                <tr style="margin: 0; padding: 0;height:20px;">
                                    <td style="border: thin; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; text-align: left; width: 22%; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 10px; font-weight: 700;" colspan="6">@Html.DisplayFor(i => account.AccountHead.AccountHeadName)</td>

                                </tr>
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(account.AccountHead.AccountHeadName))
                                {
                                    subGroups.Add(account.AccountHead.AccountHeadName);
                                }
                            }

                            <tr style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse;height:inherit;">
                                <td style="border: thin; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; text-align: left; width: 23%; height: 100%; padding: 0;">@Html.HiddenFor(i => account.AccountID, new { style = "margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" })</td>
                                <td style="border: thin; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; text-align: left; width: 23%; height: 100%; text-align: right; padding: 0;">@Html.DisplayFor(i => account.AccountName, new { style = "margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:5px;" })</td>
                                <td style="border: thin; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; text-align: right; width: 15%; height: 100%; padding: 0;" id="account_AccountID">@Html.TextBoxFor(i => account.Planned, new { style = "width:95%;text-align:right;height:21px; margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;margin-left:3px;margin-right:0px;" })</td>
                                <td style="border: thin; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; text-align: right; width: 15%; height: 100%; padding: 0;">@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0:c}", account.AccountValue, new { style = "margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:5px;" }))</td>
                                <td style="border: thin; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; text-align: right; width: 14%; height: 100%; padding: 0;">@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0:c}", account.Deviation))</td>

</tr>
}
</table>

this razor usihg for each loop so for each data it taking same id for the controlers how can i modify them
```

Comment: it is bad to have multiple fields on a page all with the same id.  Put a class on the text boxes and you can loop through them using jquery .each http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Here in razor i am using foreach loop to get those values into control so i dont know how to get diffrent id for control.please give me example of putting class on the text boxes. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add attributes to razor you add them like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor (x => x.FieldName, new { @class = "FieldClass" })
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: i have given the view please tell me how to create dynamic id for each text boxes to store value for corresponding account

Comment: if you want to set the id you can't use the for helper.  So you would have @Html.TextBox and in the part where you have new { style... you would add , id = account.AccountID.

Comment: on a side note.  if you add classes to your td elements you can set the style for all of them using the class selector and then you don't have to put all of your styles inline.  Much easier to code

Comment: yes its helpful i added id like you said and i incremented id by for loop by adding +n. now its getting different id names.